# How can I preserve image quality when combining aerials of different resolutions?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, aerial-photography

I have two different rasters that were flown at different times during the same month. One has a resolution of 4-inches, the other has a resolution of 6-inches. Using ArcGIS tools, how can I combine these rasters while preserving as much image quality as possible? I intend to use the combined output as a basemap.

Comment: Why do they need to be combined?

Comment: We've had several issues with uncombined rasters in catalog format in ArcSDE not displaying at certain scales. Having one singular SDE raster for a basemap has been optimal in solving this problem and has generally offered better performance.

Comment: Have you investigated [Mosaic Datasets](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t0000000n000000)? The helps says it can have different spatial resolutions.

Comment: Mosaic dataset is certainly the way to go. The time for loading rasters into ArcSDE servers started to wane at 9.0 and was completely gone by ArcGIS 9.3.

Comment: @Paul unfortunately Mosaic Datasets are not an option for me, as I don't have the Image Extension license to publish them to the web. However, if you move this comment into an answer I will mark it as correct as it does answer the question.